# ASP.NET and SQL In between prices with plus option

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a dropdown menu with different price ranges, my last option is 599900 +

then I use SQL to filter the results

```
sql += " AND ec.price < " + id.price.Max() + " AND ec.price > " + id.price.Min().Substring(0, 1) + "00000";
```

This works well when options have an in between (400000 - 499900)

however if the user selects 599900 + then it should get all the results with a price of 500000 or greater...how would I do this? What is happening right now when I select 599900 + my Max is 599900 and my Min is 500000 so this will only get my data between those, how do I handle the case when I want everything greater then 500000?

Hope this make sense.

Comment: I don't think this is a [tag:sql] question, you're clearly building SQL queries in some other language and that's where the interesting stuff is going on.  It seems like it's obvious that the SQL side answer is to remove the 'max' part of the WHERE.

Comment: This is in ASP.NET

Comment: How are your parameters getting populated, then?  You ultimately need some way to figure out to either not add the `<` part of the query, or you need to customize the query, or pass an arbitrarily large number that's beyond your possible number side.

Comment: if you can share the all the list values?

Comment: Have you looked at using a [`CASE` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)?